# How can I run a Sub Query in MySQL, and get only year = 2020, from Python?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, datetime, where-clause

I'm logging into a MySQL DB and running the following line of code.

```
df = pd.read_sql("Select data_date, hr, group, eno, eut, car, freq, band, hq, From fsm WHERE IN (SELECT * FROM fsm WHERE year(data_date) = '2020')", st_connection)
```

I want to select only records from 2020, so I'm using a sub query here.  At around 100M records and over 300 columns, the table is pretty huge, so I am trying to take a subset of data.  Something is off, but I can't tell what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to select only records from 2020, so I'm using a sub query here.

I don't see the point for the suqbuery at all. If you want records of 2020, then:

```
select ...
from fsm 
where data_date >= '2020-01-01' and data_date < '2021-01-01'
```

Note that this uses direct filtering against column `data_date`. This is much more efficient than applying a date function on the column, as in your original predicate: `year(data_date) = 2020`, which requires applying the function to the entire dataset before the filtering can happen, and precludes the use of an index.

Comment: "This is much more efficient than applying a date function on the column, as in your original predicate: year(data_date) = 2020" That makes sense and is good to know.

Comment: @DavidErickson: yes... you might want to read on the context of SARGable predicate (Search Argument Able).

Comment: Thank you. Conceptually this gets the job done: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable

Comment: This works fine. I was thinking of something much more complicated. Thanks for helping me get back on track here.